# Gmail account from old phone to new Galaxy S7

Tags: gmail

Ive just recently updated my phone from a motorola to a Galaxy 7 and now my husband has my old phone. How do I remove my gmail account from the old phone please without removing it from my new phone?

Comment: On your old phone go to settings>accounts> Google>Gmail (may vary a bit depending on your Android version). Tap the three button on right hand side to and choose remove account. That's it. Removing your account on old phone does not affect the account on your new phone, it will be intact.

Answer (score 0):

on your old phone go to settings -> accounts-> then select google, now you can select Gmail account you want to remove, on the action bar there are 3 dots click on it and you will see a menu saying remove account. Click on it and your are done.
hope this will help.